# Visual Studio 2019 forms for the SSIS 2019 Lookup Transformation Editor does not display correctly- lines squashed together

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, popupwindow

Visual Studio form for SSIS package Lookup task forms do not show properly' For example Lookup Transformation Editor does not display correctly for any of the selections.  The lines are squashed and the bottom cutoff in a number of them.  Could be some system setting on my PC. Here is an example

[SSIS LookupfoTransformation Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t8DT.png)

Comment: If this is the only form that displays this issue, I'd lean toward it being a bug in VS2019. However, it looks like you may be using a non-default font. Have you tried changing the font or any of the font properties? Do you have magnification set in the Windows system settings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.  I had the font magnified to 150% in the windows system configuration.  I set it back to 100% and the form display was good.  However I cannot not leave the display at 100% as the font is too small for me.
Thanks for the help  - Andrew Chirwa